How to move Laravel 11 public folder?
I have tried to search for tutorial to move the public folder, but from all the guide it seems like the code is different than version 11. The folder structure I want to move will be like:

public (public folder is here)
program (all the other files to be stored inside this folder)

I have modified the public/index.php file to be:
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// Determine if the application is in maintenance mode...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../program/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// Register the Composer autoloader...
require __DIR__.'/../program/vendor/autoload.php';

// Bootstrap Laravel and handle the request...
(require_once __DIR__.'/../program/bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleRequest(Request::capture());

However, when I try to run php artisan serve, I get the error
   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException

  The provided cwd "C:\wamp64\www\my-project\program\public" does not exist.

What are the things needed to modify to get it works?

To make artisan use a custom public folder, you can edit the artisan script to call the usePublicPath() method on the application object.
Change these lines:
$status = (require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php')
    ->handleCommand(new ArgvInput);

to:
$status = (require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php')
    ->usePublicPath('/your/public/folder')
    ->handleCommand(new ArgvInput);


Thank you for your answer. But inside the app when called public_path() it still shows old public path. How can I update it?

@user1995781 I guess the application object is created several times; in that case, you should directly modify bootstrap/app.php. Try replacing the last line })->create(); with })->create()->usePublicPath('/your/public/folder');
